# Need help validating XML against XSD in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm writing a WPF application that requires XML files to be validated. I have the following class to validate XML against one or more XSD files:

```
public class XSDValidator
{
    public List<XmlSchema> Schemas { get; set; }
    public List<String> Errors { get; set; }
    public List<String> Warnings { get; set; }

    public XSDValidator()
    {
        Schemas = new List<XmlSchema>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a schema to be used during the validation of the XML document
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="schemaFileLocation">The file path for the XSD schema file to be added for validation</param>
    /// <returns>True if the schema file was successfully loaded, else false (if false, view Errors/Warnings for reason why)</returns>
    public bool AddSchema(string schemaFileLocation)
    {
        // Reset the Error/Warning collections
        Errors = new List<string>();
        Warnings = new List<string>();

        XmlSchema schema;

        if (!File.Exists(schemaFileLocation))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("The specified XML file does not exist", schemaFileLocation);
        }

        using (var fs = new FileStream(schemaFileLocation, FileMode.Open))
        {
            schema = XmlSchema.Read(fs, ValidationEventHandler);
        }

        var isValid = !Errors.Any() && !Warnings.Any();

        if (isValid)
        {
            Schemas.Add(schema);
        }

        return isValid;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Perform the XSD validation against the specified XML document
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xmlLocation">The full file path of the file to be validated</param>
    /// <returns>True if the XML file conforms to the schemas, else false</returns>
    public bool IsValid(string xmlLocation)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(xmlLocation))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("The specified XML file does not exist", xmlLocation);
        }

        using (var xmlStream = new FileStream(xmlLocation, FileMode.Open))
        {
            return IsValid(xmlStream);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Perform the XSD validation against the supplied XML stream
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xmlStream">The XML stream to be validated</param>
    /// <returns>True is the XML stream conforms to the schemas, else false</returns>
    private bool IsValid(Stream xmlStream)
    {
        // Reset the Error/Warning collections
        Errors = new List<string>();
        Warnings = new List<string>();

        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
        {
            ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema
        };
        settings.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationEventHandler;

        foreach (var xmlSchema in Schemas)
        {
            settings.Schemas.Add(xmlSchema);
        }

        var xmlFile = XmlReader.Create(xmlStream, settings);

        while (xmlFile.Read()) { }

        return !Errors.Any() && !Warnings.Any();
    }

    private void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Severity)
        {
            case XmlSeverityType.Error:
                Errors.Add(e.Message);
                break;
            case XmlSeverityType.Warning:
                Warnings.Add(e.Message);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is open-source and can be found [here](http://satalketo.com/2013/09/validating-xml-against-xsd/). Now, it is called like so:

```
var validator = new XSDValidator();
validator.AddSchema(@"C:\code\xml\books.xsd");

foreach (CheckableListItem file in FileFullPathChecklist)
{
    if (file.IsChecked)
    {
        if (validator.IsValid(file.Filename)) 
        {
            ValidatedXMLFiles++;
        }
    }
}
```

In my testing of the XSD validation, I'm using 4 XML files: one of them, `books.xml`, corresponds to the hard-coded schema `books.xsd`. The other three are random XML files I pulled from other sources, and I have verified that they are not valid against `books.xsd`. However, upon running the code, `ValidatedXMLFiles` shows a value of 4 instead of 1.

I've verified as much as I can think of from the `XSDValidator` class; I tried manually adding a random string to `Errors`, and `IsValid` returned false in that case. One thing that I thought was interesting was, when I tried changing the schema file name to something that doesn't exist, a `TargetInvocationException` was thrown instead of the `FileNotFoundException` that I expected. I don't know if that means anything, but that's the only strange behavior I've seen. Can anyone provide any assistance?

Comment: Hi Coconut Jones, I would be very interested in looking into this. Would it be possible to get hold of the files so I can try to replicate it on my computer. I'd obviously like to make sure my code works properly.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that the validation engine will automotically know to use the books.xsd schema to validate all the xml files.

This is not correct. The xml needs to tell the validator which XSD it is supposed to be validated against.

To indicate this you set the xmlns attribute in your xml document.

For example:

```
<MyXml xmlns="http://MySchemaNamespace">
    ...
</MyXml>
```

And the schema:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           targetNamespace="http://MySchemaNamespace" 
           xmlns="http://MySchemaNamespace" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    ...
</xs:schema>
```

Otherwise the only criteria for the XML to be "valid" is that it's well formed.