# Validating an XML against referenced XSD in C# each element

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I am creating a console application to validate xml in C#.  when I open the file, validates it against the schema and when it encounters an error in a node then it comes out of node and validates next node in the file. Somehow, though, I can't seem to validate all the elements after getting the error in the node.

```
XmlDocument asset = new XmlDocument();

XmlTextReader schemaReader = new XmlTextReader("relativeSchemaPath");
XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read(schemaReader, SchemaValidationHandler);

asset.Schemas.Add(schema);

asset.Load(filename);
asset.Validate(DocumentValidationHandler);
```

i Have used the validate method but it is only giving not giving all the errors. I have referenced the links that i followed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb387037.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3740e0b5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

[Need help validating XML against XSD in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143523/need-help-validating-xml-against-xsd-in-c-sharp)

I need to validate all the elements in the file even after getting the error in a node i need to validate remaining elements in the node. i Need to list the errors for the following element missing, Case sensitivity, and sequence.

Comment: Where is your XML? It would help if you would include it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The validator will typically stop dead if it encounters badly formed XML, but should continue to read past missing/additional XML elements. However, it may end up skipping the remaining siblings as it may not be able to figure out what they should be given the previous error.

I typically setup all the settings in an XmlReaderSettings class and pass that to the reader, one thing that may give you more of the errors you want is the XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings. 
Playing with the settings in here has a significannt effect on how validation is applied especially the ValidationType property.

Have a look at

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.validationflags%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

If you still hit problems post sample XSD/XML files, and indicate what errors you expect to see